# ¿por qué un simple Count() sobre tabla con algo mas de dos millones de registros es muy lenta?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql

Tengo una tabla con con dos millones y medio de registros y tengo un procedimiento que trabajan sobre ella, cuando ejecutaba el procedimiento este tardaba hasta 30 minutos, después de revisar el procedimiento vi que no había nada "raro", identifique que la demora ocurría incluso al ejecutar un Select count(1) from tabla, esta sentencia tomaba más de 15 minutos, después de que la sentencia terminaba y se volvía a ejecutar la duración ya era menor, entiendo que es porque el motor almacena en cache. Ejecuto estas dos sentencias:
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE ;

Pero al parecer esto no es suficiente para eliminar todo lo que la base de datos almacena en cache.

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE [clientes] (
[IdentificadorEmpresa]             INT              NOT NULL,
[IdentificacionUsuario]      VARCHAR (40)     NOT NULL,
[CodigoNodo]                       VARCHAR (20)     NULL,
[TipoConexion]                     TINYINT          NULL,
[NivelTension]                     TINYINT          NULL,
[NivelTensionPrimario]             TINYINT          NULL,
[PorcentajePropiedadActivo]        TINYINT          NULL,
[IdentificadorComercializador]     INT              NULL,
[CodigoFronteraComercial]          VARCHAR (11)     NULL,
[ConsumoFacturadoKVH]              INT              NULL,
[DiasConsumoFacturado]             SMALLINT         NULL,
[CodigoCircuito]                   VARCHAR (10)     NULL,
[CodigoDane]                       INT              NULL,
[Ubicacion]                        TINYINT          NULL,
[Direccion]                        VARCHAR (50)     NULL,
[CondicionEspecial]                TINYINT          NULL,
[TipoAreaEspecial]                 TINYINT          NULL,
[CodigoAreaEspecial]               SMALLINT         NULL,
[Estrato]                          TINYINT          NULL,
[Altitud]                          SMALLINT         NULL,
[Longitud]                         DECIMAL (17, 15) NULL,
[Latitud]                          DECIMAL (17, 15) NULL,
[Autogenerador]                    TINYINT          NULL,
[ExportaEnergia]                   BIT              NULL,
[CapacidadAutogeneradorKw]         DECIMAL (10, 2)  NULL,
[TipoGeneracion]                   TINYINT          NULL,
[CodigoFronteraAutogeneracion]     VARCHAR (11)     NULL,
[FechaEntradaOperacion]            DATE             NULL,
[ContratoRespaldo]                 BIT              NULL,
[CapacidadContratoRespaldo]        DECIMAL (10, 2)  NULL,
[PeriodicidadFactura]              TINYINT          NULL,
[GeneraFactura]                    BIT              DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[Ciclo]                            TINYINT          NULL,
[NumeroServicio]                   INT              NULL,
[InstalacionAlumbrado]             BIT              DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[CodigoConsumidorAlumbradoPublico] VARCHAR (20)     NULL,
[TipoFactura]                      TINYINT          NULL,
[IdentificacionFactura]            VARCHAR (20)     NULL,
[RefacturacionConsumoUsuariokwh]   INT              NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_clientes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdentificadorEmpresa] ASC, [IdentificacionUsuario] ASC));
```

el motor de base de datos es: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8, como pueden ver la base de datos esta en azure(plan estandar 10DTU).

¿Saben por que tarda tanto un simple count()?¿Conocen una forma de limpiar todo el cache en sql azure para optimizar en base al tiempo real de las sentencias?

Comment: Diego, millones no son pocos registros. Pero si tu primary key es autoincremental y no se borran los registros podrias ver cual es el id mas grande y sabes cual es tu count

Comment: @RamiroBarone lo que dijiste es incorrecto.

Comment: La cache no es un botón de "turbo." La cache sirve cuando accedes repetidas veces a los mismos registros. No te optimiza el primer acceso al registro. Y si procesas muchos registros, se llena la cache y hay que sacar registros de ella para meter en cache los nuevos registros. No soy un experto en BD, pero para una operación de este tipo no me extrañaría que la cache fuera más ineficiente que no usar la cache. En todo caso, no conseguirás que vaya más rápido limpiando la cache.

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro que mejore en algo, pero ¿tienes alguna columna indexada? prueba hacer un `select count(columna) from tabla`

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que es un simple `select count(1) from tabla`? ¿Sobre una tabla? 
¿sin condiciones? ¿Cuál es el plan de ejecución?. Esto, porque un `select count` simple como ese debiera basarse en un índice (el de la llave primaria por ejemplo), y sería interesante ver si se tarda tanto utilizando el índice (cosa que no creo, pero explicaría que tienes que comprar más potencia de procesador) o qué está utilizando y por qué, para tardarse tanto.

Answer (score 1):

A primera vista tu pregunta no parece que tenga que ver nada con la tabla, y si con otras posibles causas.
Lo primero es verificar que realmente cuando haces un

```
select count(1) from clientes;
```

realmente, está leyendo la clave primaria como tú crees o está intentando sacar el dato de otro sitio. Ya que el plan de ejecución puede haber determinado que no es ese el lugar a buscar. Te pongo una captura de ejemplo.

[image: Resultado]

Como puedes ver de la captura que te he puesto, en mi caso, la consulta ha determinado que mejor le viene utilizar un índice nonClustered en vez de PK_iaiEvents.

No es que crea, que sea este el problema, pero una cosa es lo que creemos, y a veces otra lo que ejecuta.

La segunda cosa que tienes que mirar, es que indicas que es un procedimiento almacenado, y es bastante probable, que por los síntomas, puedas sufriendo parameter sniffing.

Fácil de comprobar.

Haz la misma query sin el procedimiento almacenado, y mira a ver cuanto dura.

A partir de ahí.

Actualiza las estadísticas

```
exec sp_updatestats
```

[update stats](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-updatestats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Recompila el procedure

exec sp_recompile procedure;

[Option recompile why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864934/option-recompile-is-always-faster-why)

Fuerza el recompilado de las consultas.

```
select * from ....where ...
option (recompile);
```

[Sugerencias de consultas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15)

Te dejo un enlace a un artículo que ha escrito estos días un compañero sobre el asunto. Está en brasileño, pero no te costará seguirlo utilizando una herramienta de traducción.

[parameter sniffing](https://wordpress.com/read/feeds/86586257/posts/2892637150)